# Apache default website root folder

Tags: apache2

Is it safe to change the appache default website root folder to somewhere in user home? I wonder if it is okay to do. Because otherwise I have to save the default site by another name and then run apache commands to disable the default site and enable mine. So why not just edit the default site and change the document root and directory to somewhere in my home.

Answer (score 2):

it is safe, it's all about permissions, i put my document root within my home directory and
execute `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ~/jhano/public_html

Answer (score 1):

First it is OK and safe to point the document root to some directory within your home directory.
Saying that, please notice that there is no difference over changing the owner of the current document root to be you. You can easily do so by execution `chown -R <user> <webdir>` where *user* is your username and *webdir* is current apache documents root where you place your site files.